# Why should I use `return` when the script is functional without that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, return

I've created a script using Python to parse the movie names and its years spread across multiple pages from a torrent site and write them to a csv file. It is working errorlessly and writing the data to a csv file without any issues.

I did the whole thing without the usage of this very line `return itemlist` within my `get_data()` function and as I create this function `write_data()` fully independent so I wrote the data to a CSV file taken from this list `itemlist` located under the variable `URLS`.

If I keep the existing design intact, is it necessary to use this very line `return itemlist` which is commented out now? If so, why?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URLS = ["https://yts.am/browse-movies?page={}".format(page) for page in range(1,6)]
itemlist = []

def get_data(links):
    for url in links:
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        for record in soup.select('.browse-movie-bottom'):
            items = {}
            items["Name"] = record.select_one('.browse-movie-title').text
            items["Year"] = record.select_one('.browse-movie-year').text
            itemlist.append(items)
    # return itemlist

def write_data():
    with open("outputfile.csv","w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,['Name','Year'])
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in itemlist:
            writer.writerow(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data(URLS)
    write_data()
```

Comment: Well, you don't *use* that result anyway.

Comment: If you're going to return the list, it should also be *created* inside the function. That would make the function more reusable and testable, too. Similarly it should be passed into the second function, which is **not** currently *"fully independent"*. But if the script is functional, why do you think you need to make any changes to it?

Comment: I heard that using `return` within a function is a good practice and that is the only reason of my asking whether what I'm doing is right @jonrsharpe?

Comment: is this `Well, you don't use that result anyway` any sort of suggestion @usr2564301?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *existing design* you don't need that line because your `get_data` intend to *modify list from outer scope* instead of *return list*.

But if you want to rename `itemlist` you need to rename it also in both `get_data` and `write_data` (in all functions that might use it)

You might need `return itemlist` if you define `write_data` as

```
def write_data(some_list):
    ...
```

and use it as

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_data(get_data(URLS))
```

In this case `write_data` receives list returned by `get_data` and you don't need to define `itemlist = []` outside `get_data`

Comment: Thanks sir @Andersson for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this one specific case your script will work. But wouldn't it be nice to reuse your function somewhere else? In a different file, you could say:

```
from xy import get_data
links = ["url1", "url2",...]
a = get_data(links)
```

and work with it without the need of rewriting the function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this in a Python console:

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
...
```

Aphorism 2 states that "Explicit is better than implicit.". Therefore, I think its better for readability to inform a potential user of these functions what side effects is expected by calling them. And to achieve that, you need to return the list of data you get, and give it to `write_data` to do its work.

As a self-contained script, your script is good. As a library, it's not practical unless you return the list you populate.

Answer (score 0):

Using global variable in any programming language is not appreciated. If you want to reuse your functions you can have the return statement and pass the result to the write_data function. I would suggest you to have a look at what @andersson has given above

Answer (score -1):

In your code, itemlist is the global variable. Return statement is not required with the above cases.